# MS C++ 2012 linker hangs but only in debug mode x64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I just upgraded to MSVC 2012 Express (which is saying trial btw. I wonder why as it should be free). After lots of changes from MSVC 2005 it started working, but the linker hangs, but only in debug mode x64, in all other 3 modes it works! Here are the commandline arguments (I called it from a script, but it does the same thing when called from IDE).

> *cl.exe /fp:precise /Od /MTd /bigobj /RTCscu /Zi /GS- /TP /Fd"!temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/vc70.pdb" /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL /D_WINDOWS
>   /DWIN64 /Fo"!temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/main.obj"
>   /FR"!temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/" /I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 11.0/Vc/include" /I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows
>   Kits/8.0/Include/um" /I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows
>   Kits/8.0/Include/shared" /I "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Intel/IPP/6.1.2.041/em64t/include" /D_MBCS /c /W3 /EHsc /GF /Gd
>   /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /nologo MDrummer/VSTEffects/main.cpp*
>
> *link.exe !temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/icon.res !temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/main.obj
>   !temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/resourcesrotary.obj
>   !temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary/mlibrary.obj mlibraryasm_x64_debug.lib
>   kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib
>   advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib
>   odbccp32.lib comctl32.lib wsock32.lib winmm.lib msimg32.lib psapi.lib
>   opengl32.lib Glu32.lib freetype_x64_debug.lib zlib_x64_debug.lib
>   libpng_x64_debug.lib libtiff_x64_debug.lib libjpeg_x64_debug.lib
>   giflib_x64_debug.lib bzip2_x64_debug.lib libflac_x64_debug.lib
>   vstsdk3_x64_debug.lib ippcoreem64tl.lib ippsemergedem64t.lib
>   ippsmergedem64t.lib ippiemergedem64t.lib ippimergedem64t.lib
>   ippvmemergedem64t.lib ippvmmergedem64t.lib /OUT:"c:/program
>   files/vstplugins/MeldaProductionx64/Modulation/MRotary.dll"
>   /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
>   /DEF:"D:/Programming/Mlibrary/mvstplugin.def" /DLL
>   /IMPLIB:"D:/Programming/MDrummer/!temp/DebugDebug1/MRotary.lib"
>   /PDB:"c:/program
>   files/vstplugins/MeldaProductionx64/Modulation/MRotary.pdb"
>   /LIBPATH:"D:/Programming/Mlibrary/library"
>   /LIBPATH:"D:/Programming/MDrummer"
>   /LIBPATH:"D:/Programming/MDrummer/!temp/DebugDebug1"
>   /LIBPATH:"D:/Programming/MDrummer/c:\program
>   files\vstplugins\MeldaProductionx64" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Vc/lib/amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Lib/win8/um/x64" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Intel/IPP/6.1.2.041/em64t/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Intel/IPP/6.1.2.041/em64t/stublib" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /nologo
>   /MANIFEST:NO*

Any ideas? I searched there have been troubles with this, but nothing seems related to this specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently it starts working if I remove "/OPT:REF /OPT:ICF", but why and why only in such specific circumstances, that's a question...